# See page size statistics in firefox?

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to see the total size of the page you are currently viewing in Firefox, or a plugin that supports this? I want to know the size of the images downloaded seperate from the size of the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to go to tools->pageinfo. There, you'll be able tio find various data about the page including size of the page, individual files that make up the page and their sizes, site permissions and security data which the site provides.

Here's how it looks:
[image: page statistics window]

Comment: Answer now outdated - FF doesn't display Size anymore (currently FF 88.0)

Comment: @Conrad Well, the question is 10 years old now...

Comment: People still search for answers to this question - that's how I got here  They like to keep answers "up to date" if possible...

Answer (score 0):

WebDeveloper - Information - View document size – will show **real** sizes split by types. Page info just lies and tells about HTML only.

Example output:

```
Document Size 
    Documents (16 files)    144 KB (128 KB uncompressed)
    Images (16 files)   114 KB
    Objects (0 files)   
    Scripts (3 files)   26 KB
    Style Sheets (2 files)  33 KB
    Total   316 KB (301 KB uncompressed)
```

File info responded with `Size 133,71 KB (136923 bytes)`.

Comment: Can I access that info using developer tools (`F12`)?

Comment: Where to find "WebDeveloper - Information - View document size"?

Answer (score 0):

Hamburger menu -> More Tools -> Web Developer Tools (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

Select the 'Network' tab.

Load or reload the page, and at the bottom it will show the size of each file downloaded plus the total page size.

[image: webdevtools]